# Using glide with subdirectories

Tags: go, directory, vendor, glide-golang

I have the following structure for my project

MyCode

== main.go

== user

==== user.go

I would like to build my code with 'go build' so in main.go I have a

```
import "user"
```

so that I can access the code in the package in that directory. In order to build this properly I would need my user directory inside my vendor directory. However, when I do a 'glide install' the user directory is deleted. I do not want to move my user directory into my vendor directory manually everytime.

The goal is to git clone my project, do a glide install then a go build and have it work. Is there a way I can have glide move my user directory into the vendor directory without having to do it manually?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the full path to your user pkg? Your life will be a lot easier if you develop your Go programs like everyone else.

Comment: The full path to the package would be, in my case

    'import "./user"'

. That will fail to build due to a compliant about local imports. I could include the folder name like 'import "MyCode/user"' but if I change the folder name the code won't compile and I would need all references to MyCode changed to the new folder name

Comment: Why would the folder name change? All of the code in MyCode aka your application should be code that is written for MyCode and be imported with the path prefix of "MyCode/". If you you have code that you plan on reusing in other projects that code should be under a different path/repo and MyCode should/could list that code as a dependency.

Comment: It is common for me to git clone the project more than once in the same directory so that I'm doing different work in different folders. You can't have two folders with the same name so one is renamed but if I do that the code will no longer build.
I can try to avoid renaming the folder and changing my import statements to see how painful it is.